# Insert a line of comment in Visual Studio

Tags: printing, insert, visual-studio-2012, comments, line

I'm looking for a shortcut in Visual C# Studio 2012 ( if it exists ), that will insert a line of comment like so:

```
/******************************************************************************/
```

These make the code more readable for me. What I want to achieve is to separate blocks of code which are written to achieve different things. Let's say:

```
/****************************************************************************/
{
        // block that does something
}

/****************************************************************************/

{
        // block that does something else
}

/****************************************************************************/
```

What I don't want to do is press and hold "*" until it prints the right number of stars.
Don't want to copy paste such comments.

Any hints?

**--------------EDIT--------------**
Solution found:
*Steve Fenton* - creating a snippet, tyvm ;)

Comment: Make a keyboard macro. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom code snippets in Visual Studio that will speed this up, but please discuss this to ensure everyone working on the code is happy with the convention. In a modern IDE this kind of commenting is really noisy and many people don't want the code littered with this kind of delimiter.

You import snippet files using `Tools > Code Snippet Manager` and place them under the appropriate language.

Once imported (you may need to restart Visual Studio) you type the shortcut and hit tab... i.e. `bigc` then `TAB`.

File: bigc.snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
          <Title>Crazy Big Comment</Title>
          <Description>Inserts a crazy big comment block.</Description>
          <Author>Steve Fenton</Author>
          <Shortcut>bigc</Shortcut>
          <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
          </SnippetTypes>          
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="CSharp" Kind="any">
                <![CDATA[
                    // ************************************************************************
                ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

There are instructions on [creating custom snippets on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292073/Extending-Visual-Studio-Part-1-Creating-Code-Snipp) - written for 2010, but applicable to 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the same exact thing as you're asking for, but I think supplies the same functionality and a little more.
There are Regions you can use in Visual Studio that would break your code into sections that are shrinkable and expandable for easy separation of code blocks.

For Example:

```
#Region "This is the code to be collapsed" 
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.Container
    Dim WithEvents Form1 As System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
        Me.Text = "Form1" 
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Source:[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xywk05b.aspx)

Comment: knew about that functionality, but was searching for what I was actually asking for. Combining your idea with mine can come in handy sometimes though. Thx for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing procedures large enough to warrant separating out sections into individual code blocks, I'd suggest that's a good point to start creating sub procedures.  Visual studio provides support to make a sub procedure if you select the code and right click Refactor | Extract method.

Alternatively, have you looked at the regions keyword?  This has intent similar to your requested functionality but has support from the Visual Studio IDE.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek(v=vs.110).aspx